# Which characters are considered "word" characters

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, character-set

Fulltext searchin with InnoDB in MySQL only includes certain characters referred to in the docs as "word characters" and mentioned [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html):

> For the built-in full-text parser, you can change the set of characters that are considered word characters in several ways, as described in the following...

My question is, for a given character set, how can I determine *which characters* are considered "word" characters?  My table is utf_general_ci. I did a bit of trial and error and found for instance, that "¬" is not treated as a word character but "Ω" is. I'm looking for either a clearly defined reference or a tool of some support so that I can find this out without doing trial and error.

Comment: Note that `Ω` is a Greek "letter"; `¬` is a mathematical symbol.

Comment: @RickJames - you're right but `∑` is a greek letter and through trial and error I've discovered that it's *not* treated as a word character, although `Ω` is.

Comment: Interesting.  How about expanding your experiment to determine which Greek letters are "word" letters (in upper and lower case).

Comment: I'm using these as a workaround for a fulltext search which I just posted about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58241383/1767412).  At the moment I only need a couple to act as substitutions so I didn't do anything very exhaustive.  The ones I found that are treated as word chars are: `Ω` `œ` `π` `ß` `µ`.

Answer (score 1):

The characters considered for forming a **word**, is explained in the [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html):

> The MySQL FULLTEXT implementation regards any sequence of true word
>   characters (**letters, digits, and underscores**) as a word. That sequence
>   may also contain apostrophes ('), but not more than one in a row. This means that 
>   aaa'bbb is regarded as one word, but aaa''bbb is regarded as two
>   words. Apostrophes at the beginning or the end of a word are stripped
>   by the FULLTEXT parser; 'aaa'bbb' would be parsed as aaa'bbb.

**Regarding Delimiters**:

> The built-in FULLTEXT parser determines where words start and end by
>   looking for certain delimiter characters; for example,   (space), `,`
>   (comma), and . (period).

Besides the above, there are Storage engine specific limits as well, on the minimum word size:

> Any word that is too short is ignored. The default minimum length of
>   words that are found by full-text searches is three characters for
>   InnoDB search indexes, or four characters for MyISAM.

Now, regarding the list of defined "True Word Characters", MySQL has given flexibilities, to be able to add/remove additional characters, for word criteria. As stated in the [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html#fulltext-modify-character-set):

> Suppose that you want to treat the hyphen character ('-') as a word
>   character. Use one of these methods:
>
> - Modify the MySQL source: In storage/innobase/handler/ha_innodb.cc (for InnoDB), or in storage/myisam/ftdefs.h (for MyISAM), see the
>     true_word_char() and misc_word_char() macros. Add '-' to one of those
>     macros and recompile MySQL.
> - Modify a character set file: This requires no recompilation. The true_word_char() macro uses a “character type” table to distinguish
>     letters and numbers from other characters. . You can edit the contents
>     of the  array in one of the character set XML files to
>     specify that '-' is a “letter.” Then use the given character set for
>     your FULLTEXT indexes.

Now looking at the source code `ha_innodb.cc` [here](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.7/storage/innobase/handler/ha_innodb.cc):

```
#define true_word_char(c, ch) ((c) & (_MY_U | _MY_L | _MY_NMR) || (ch) == '_')
```

For some simple character-sets like `latin1`, one can edit the `<ctype><map>` array in the respective `.xml` file: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.7/sql/share/charsets/latin1.xml#L25

However, **utf8** being a complex character-set, it is implemented in the [ctype-utf8.c file](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.7/storage/innobase/handler/ha_innodb.cc#L6557) . It contains the complete character set definitions. Now,  array elements are bit values. Each element describes the attributes of a single character in the character set. Each attribute is associated with a bitmask, as defined in [`include/m_ctype.h`](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.7/include/m_ctype.h#L714) file:

```
#define _MY_U   01  /* Upper case */
#define _MY_L   02  /* Lower case */
#define _MY_NMR 04  /* Numeral (digit) */
```

So, the characters having attributes associated with above bitmasks will be considered as true word character. Check out some explanation here --> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/character-arrays.html

Finally, there is a list of **stopwords** (InnoDB has limited list, but MyISAM has quite a big list), which are ignored. Eg: `about`, `are`, `com` etc.

> Words in the stopword list are ignored. A stopword is a word such as
>   “the” or “some” that is so common that it is considered to have zero
>   semantic value. There is a built-in stopword list, but it can be
>   overridden by a user-defined list.

Comment: Isn't ¬ a letter?  The definition is too vague - I need some way to know what constitutes a "letter" in a given charset otherwise I'm just guessing.

Comment: @billynoah Check the edited answer. Unfortunately, there isn't any proper documentation giving out all the characters considered in the uppercase, lowercase and numeric lists. So, only way left is to explore the source code files (as given in the answer above), to figure out for specific characters.

Answer (score 0):

(Really a Comment, but need formatting, so writing this as an Answer.)

Be cautious of look-alikes:

```
β  GREEK SMALL LETTER BETA
ß  LATIN SMALL LETTER SHARP S  (German "ss")  (You had this)

μ  GREEK SMALL LETTER MU
µ  MICRO SIGN                    (You had this)

œ  LATIN SMALL LIGATURE OE     (in old writings; often written as "oe")
```

I would *expect* "LATIN" and "GREEK" letters to be letters in the Fulltext "word" sense.  However, this does not fully match the pattern you discovered.

On the other hand, `µsec` for "microsecond" would probably be a FULLTEXT "word".